# How to enable/install HTTP/2 on Virtualmin in CentOS7

Tags: apache, centos, http2, webmin, virtualmin

I have Virtualmin installed on my CentOS7 server and few websites are currently running on this server. There's no separate Apache installation because it is using Virtualmin. However I need to install / enable HTTP/2 on my server but current resources on the internet are not helpful enough to learn how to do this since I have a Virtualmin installation on which few sites are hosted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/2 support was only added with Apache 2.4.17, therefore the only way to make it work on CentOS 7 is to rebuild it manually. OpenSSL version 1.0.2 is already available with CentOS 7 though.

Perhaps the easiest way would be is to upgrade to the distro that already ships needed version of Apache.

I cannot recommend CentOS 8 due to [recent events](https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/centos-8-lifecycle-end-2021/108483), however Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Debian 10 are both supported with Virtualmin and have latest versions of Apache. In the future we will support any 1:1 compatible forks/clones of RHEL; recently we fixed RHEL 8 support as well and CentOS 8 Stream is also supported.

Comment: CentOS 7 provides optionally Apache Web Server 2.4.34 via SCL (`yum install centos-release-scl-rh`, then `yum install httpd24-httpd`, maybe `yum search httpd24-httpd` to see other modules/extensions etc.), *but* I am not sure if Virtualmin is able to handle that properly because of different filesystem paths.